# Deploying an EAR in jBoss AS 7 that contains a web-services in a WAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

i've an EAR file structured as reported:

```
myEar.ear
|
+- META-INF
|  |
|  +- MANIFEST.MF
|  +- application.xml
|
+- lib
|  |
|  +- aJar.jar
|
+- aWar.war
```

The MANIFEST.MF is autogenerated and blank, in the application.xml there is only the warfile entry.

When i deploy it in the jBoss Management Console the web-service contained by the war is not displayed. If i put the war directly it's displayed instead.

Have you any advice in this issue?

Thanks,
Dario

Comment: Just curious: if `application.xml` contains only war why do you need `lib` folder in your ear? Maybe you've just forgot to include `<library-directory>` in your ear descriptor?

Comment: I thought if the library is needed only by the EAR content there is no need to declare in application.xml. I'a newbie in j2ee specifications.

Comment: ok, see response for correct application.xml, remove EJB <module> node and deploy.

Comment: i've done some tests on how deploy an _ws-servlet_ in an EAR (for work reasons i've to do with IBM WebSphere, and there _ws-servlets_ in EARs works) but i think there is something that I sink :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to comment. Here is common application.xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">

  <module>
    <!-- EJB Module -->
    <ejb>ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <!-- WEB Module -->
    <web>
      <web-uri>warfile.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/context_root</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <!-- Libraries, available both to web and ejb modules -->
  <library-directory>libs</library-directory>
</application>
```

If you have no EJB - just remove the first module node.

Comment: Appling this structure at the EAR file doesn't resolve my doubt. The web-service respond at the endpoint but in the jBoss Management does not appear in the "registered webservice endpoints". edit: as i said if i put the war directly out of EAR i saw it.

Comment: this was my mistake in application.xml writing (copy and paste cuts some declaration in the outer tag...).